# How do I do a multi row insert using ODBCConnection in .net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, oracle, odbc

I have an application that inserts rows into an Oracle DB using ODBC (Setup in ODBCAdministrator), currently it binds the parameters and does the insert one row at a time. This generally works fine, but sometimes when there are a lot of rows and the db is non-local network overhead becomes a slowdown.

I was thinking if I could insert multiple rows at a time I could cut down on that.

Looking here, it seems ODBC should support that
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/using-arrays-of-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15

> To use arrays of parameters, the application calls SQLSetStmtAttr with an Attribute argument of SQL_ATTR_PARAMSET_SIZE to specify the number of sets of parameters.

I'm not seeing how to set that in the .net world, nor does just setting my params to arrays work.

Maybe I need to cast/convert the ODBC connection to something else?

Comment: Your link it arrays of parameters, not an array of rows.  You could use a BulkCopy which will copy a table from another database or a DataTable.

Comment: Populate a DataTable with all the data, then save it all using a data adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure with ODBC, but you just need multiple queries in your command text. If you are doing a parameterized query, then it would look something like:

```
const int fieldCount = 3;

StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
List<OdbcParameter> parameters = new List<OdbcParameter>(fieldCount * rowsToInsert.Count);

sql.Append("INSERT INTO MyTable (A, B, C) VALUES (@A0, @B0, @C0);");
parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@A0", rowsToInsert[0].A));
parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@B0", rowsToInsert[0].B));
parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@C0", rowsToInsert[0].C));

for (int i = 1; i < rowsToInsert.Count; i++)
{
    sql.AppendLine().Append($"INSERT INTO MyTable (A, B, C) VALUES (@A{i}, @B{i}, @C{i});");
    parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter($"@A{i}", rowsToInsert[i].A));
    parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter($"@B{i}", rowsToInsert[i].B));
    parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter($"@C{i}", rowsToInsert[i].C));
}

OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql.ToString(), dbConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: That's just some rough pseudo code.  The cmd should be in a using block. The reason I went with a `List<>(fieldCount * rowsToInsert.Count)` is making the assumption that all Inserts are going to the same table with the same number of fields - so it initializes the List<> having a capacity the exact size we need. This prevents it having to copy the internal array List<> uses every time the capacity hits (which has a default capacity of 4). Technically, you could just use an array instead of a list, but then in the for loop, you need to take i and calculate x, y, and z index for a, b, and c.

Answer (score 0):

If it ends up that you must loop through the input, be sure you are only creating the command and parameters once outside the loop. Only the values of the parameters change inside the loop. The connection is opened once outside the loop.

```
Private Sub Insert()
    Using cn As New OdbcConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OdbcCommand("Insert Into Table (A,B,C) Values(@A,@B,@C);", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@A", OdbcType.NVarChar)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@B", OdbcType.NVarChar)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@C", OdbcType.NVarChar)
        cn.Open()
        For Each row In SomethingWithRows
            cmd.Parameters("@A").Value = row(0)
            cmd.Parameters("@B").Value = row(1)
            cmd.Parameters("@C").Value = row(2)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Not familiar with the proper parameter names in ODBC/Oracle.

Comment: This just inserts 1 row at a time still, I want to insert multiple rows.